# Reflection of power at low frequencies?

Tags: reflection, power, radio-frequency

Assume you have an AC signal source outputting 0dBm of power and connected to that are two resistors one of 50 ohms and another 100 ohms. The reflection coefficient is given by:

[image]

It seems like this equation is frequency independent. Calculating the reflection coefficient for these resistances:

[image]

My question is then, does this mean that around $(0.33)^2=11$% of the voltage wave is reflected travelling from the 50 ohm resistor to the 100 ohm resistor no matter what the frequency is?

I've heard contradicting information that reflections don't occur when the length of a circuit element is less than $λ/10$ or that they settle quite quickly so you don't need to take them into account. I would appreciate some clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: This question seems to be using a standard equation wrongly. The reflection coeffcient formula is for a terminated transmission line, where $Z_0$ is the characteristic impedance and $Z_L$ is the terminating impedance. But the question seems to envisage two discrete resistors. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @CWPP My question is simply: does reflection of power also occur at lower frequencies to the same degree, when there are resistive impedance discontinuities similar to those found in a transmission line? My question arises from the fact that power is completely reflected even at low frequencies for an open circuit (which can be measured using a directional coupler).

Comment: yes: see my answer to [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/721636/what-causes-the-behavior-of-the-increasing-transient-current-in-a-circuit-with-a/721883#721883)

Comment: @CWPP Thanks so if that is the case, can you substitute a resistive value for Z0 as I have done? I'm just wondering if you use the same formula as a transmission line to calculate how much power is reflected at lower frequencies where transmission line effects are negligible.

Comment: Why do you say transmission line effects are negligible? The answer to that other question is using the transmission line concepts at effectively DC, except for the switch-on.

Comment: @CWPP I say this because I've heard that transmission line effects only become important when the line length is greater than λ/10. Still I'm very interested to get an answer if I can use the reflection coefficient for a circuit with two different resistors as opposed to a line with a characteristic impedance.